# How to check the image file size in jquery?

Tags: jquery, image, image-size

I have a button while clicking that button I need to get the image file size

```
function attachPhoto()
{
    var path="http://www.w3schools.com/images/pulpit.jpg";// i need to check size of image
}

<input type="button" style="width:30%" onClick=" attachPhoto()" />
```

Comment: what are you attaching the photo to?

Answer (score 0):

`$('element').width()`  or `$('element').height()`

Comment: Thank you am having only path,,here how to get?

Comment: i don't understand exactly what you need, can you be a little more clear so that i can be of help

Comment: hai gaspyr i update my code view this,,,i have a button while clicking that button i need to get the image size(mentioned in path)

Comment: wat can i get in window.aLERT..i need to get the image sizee mentioned in kb or mb

Comment: LMAO, why didn't you say you wanted the file size of the image and not its dimensions :).Hold on i write another suggestion

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15002/discussion-between-user966784-and-gaspyr)

Comment: quickly check both these links for retrieving the file size of an image from database with PHP:

* http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/736180-how-find-out-image-size-stored-database

* http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/224758/using-php-to-upload-an-image-into-an-sql-database-and-then-displaying-on-a-profile-p

Answer (score 0):

`$('image').width()` and `$('image').height()`

Only after it has fully loaded (maybe attach it to the `.load()` event).

Comment: am having only path ,,,by using path how to get kindly sample code

Comment: You must insert into the page an img tag pointing to that path, attach to its load event a function that checks width & height: `$('img').load(function(){ var w= $(this).width(); var h= $(this).height() });`

Comment: What i told you is still valid, create a (maybe hidden) img tag with src="your path" and in its load event check width & height like the code above

Comment: @LordSpectre you can't call `.width()` on a hidden element.

Comment: @Alnitak Not on a _display:none_ but on a _visibility:hidden_ you can.

Comment: @LordSpectre my real point is that you should use `new Image()` for a completely off-screen node, and not put it in the DOM at all.

Comment: It seems better but I don't know if the image is loaded if not inserted into the DOM. If it works it's better anyway.

Comment: hai is it possible to get the sizein (kb or mb) using image width and height ?

Comment: @user966784 you can get that via the Content-Length header (in bytes). You can read the headers from an Ajax request I think. I thought you meant the dimension (w*h), not the size (bytes).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the dimensions of a file using only a URL, you need to use an external language like PHP. jQuery can't retrieve file properties.

One way of doing it would be to load the image somewhere offscreen and get the $('image').width() & $('image').height() but it's not an ideal way.

The best way would be to use an ajax call to a php script that would check the dimensions of the file and return it to jQuery.

Do you have access to a php server?

Comment: loading to an off-screen `Image` would be far far easier than a server side PHP script...

Comment: @Alnitak True, but you need to load the image. If he needs to do this for 100 images, loading time is something to take in consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-jQuery solution:

```
function attachPhoto() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        alert([img.width, img.height]);
    } 
    img.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/images/pulpit.jpg";
}
```

Note that the image size will *only* be available once the file is loaded, and the `onload` callback will be called *asynchronously*.  If you want other stuff to happen once you know the size that must be triggered from *inside* that callback.

Comment: How can i get the size like mb or kb.is it possible to get the size(kb or mb) using width and height

Comment: @user966784 oh, you want _that_ image size...  (sigh)