# Need to get the image properties as kb or mb in jquery

Tags: jquery, image, image-size

```
function attachPhoto() {
 var path="http://www.w3schools.com/images/pulpit.jpg";// i need to check size of image
 }
```

i have a button while clicking am getting the properties of image(size in kb or mb)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining image file size + dimensions via Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310378/determining-image-file-size-dimensions-via-javascript)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253266/how-to-have-jquery-get-image-size-in-bytes-not-image-dimensions

Comment: i need to check the image size is how many kilobytes or megabytes?

Comment: It's a duplicate of your own question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847629/how-to-check-the-image-file-size-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot get the image size using jQuery. You will need to process the file using server-side code.